# I find Premiere Pro's interface not intuitive at all, is there a better alternative?

Tags: video-editing

I use Premiere mostly to extract clips from long podcasts/interviews and sometimes to assemble various clips together with some transition between each.

Which alternative to PP can I use that accomplishes this while being a lot more simple and intuitive in terms of UX?

Comment: Operating System?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [OpenShot](https://github.com/OpenShot/openshot-qt).

- The UX is mature but not too complex
- Extracting parts of audio/videos appears an easy task
- Available for Linux, Windows and even MacOS
- It's easy to split videos into smaller parts: [image]
  You can keep both sides on slicing or only one.

Comment: Thanks, you sure it allows to do what I need to do? I saw nothing about clips on their YT channel.

Comment: I've added a fourth bullet point. If I understand you correctly, it's really important for you to split the clips. I find it quite easy to trim videos that I have imported to my project. Maybe you should try it out to be sure that it suits you.